# Standardize agglomerative feature clustering across samples or features?

Tags: feature-selection, scikit-learn, standardization, hierarchical-clustering

I know that typically, one has a feature matrix of *n* samples by *m* features.  Let's say I have a matrix *X* in this format.  If I was going to perform hierarchical clustering on the samples, I know I would want to standardize each *n*-length vector of features so that the distances between each feature are comparable.

If I was going to perform hierarchical clustering on the *m* features instead (to eventually do feature selection), would I still standardize the *n*-length vectors of features or would I standardize the *m*-length vectors of each sample? If I applied the same algorithm to cluster the features, it would be the transposed matrix of *X*, so I'm not sure which direction to standardize on (or rather, if I should standardize before or after transposing the matrix *X*).

Thank you!